# PHPExcel (BIFF) creates corrupt files

Tags: java, php, excel, phpexcel, xls

I use PHPExcel to create an old (XLS) Excel-Spreadsheet. It seems to be working, but If want to import the generated files into another Webapplication (JAVA) it thorws the following Error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: block[ 2 ] already removed - does your POIFS have circular or duplicate block references?
```

My PHP Code looks like this:

```
require_once './lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';

$CustomObjectsHeader = array("CUSTOM_STRUCTURE_ID","NAME","LABEL","UPPER_STRUCTURE_VALUE_ID","STATE","VALUE_TEXT_01","VALUE_TEXT_02","VALUE_TEXT_03","VALUE_TEXT_04","VALUE_TEXT_05","VALUE_TEXT_06","VALUE_TEXT_07","VALUE_TEXT_08","VALUE_TEXT_09","VALUE_TEXT_10","VALUE_TEXT_11","VALUE_TEXT_12","VALUE_TEXT_13","VALUE_TEXT_14","VALUE_TEXT_15","VALUE_INT_16","VALUE_INT_17","VALUE_INT_18","VALUE_INT_19","VALUE_DATETIME_20","VALUE_DATETIME_21","VALUE_FLOAT_22","VALUE_FLOAT_23","VALUE_MEDIA_24","VALUE_MEDIA_25","VALUE_MEDIA_26","VALUE_MEDIA_27","VALUE_MEDIA_28","VALUE_MEDIA_29","VALUE_MEDIA_30","VALUE_MEDIA_31","VALUE_MEDIA_32","VALUE_MEDIA_33","VALUE_RICHTEXT_34","VALUE_RICHTEXT_35","VALUE_RICHTEXT_36","VALUE_RICHTEXT_37","VALUE_RICHTEXT_38","AFFILIATE");
$line = array("asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf adfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf","asdfasdf aasfasdfasdfas dfa sdfadfasdfadfasdf ads fasdfa dsfasdf asdfasdf asdf adsf asdf");
$CustomObjects = array($CustomObjectsHeader);
array_push($CustomObjects,$line);
array_push($CustomObjects,$line);

$excelDoc = new PHPExcel();
$excelDoc->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$excelDoc->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($CustomObjects, null, 'A1');
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excelDoc, 'Excel5');
$writer->save("test.xls");
```

If I reduce the numbers of rows an content of the Arrays, it works properly.

And if I open the generated XLS-File in Excel and save it again, the JAVA-Webapp could import the files even if they are very large.

Any Ideas how to create the Excel correctly?

Comment: You're so sure that PHPExcel creates the file incorrectly because java can't open it..... have you considered the possibility that java is wrong, because MS Excel can read the PHPExcel generated file correctly?

Comment: Yes possible. But if I open the generated file in Excel and save it again it works. I could find several entries in google. But no one has any ideas. https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55124